# How to prevent pieces of colored text in the command line turning back white using std::wcout?

Tags: c++, cmd, visual-studio-2022

I recently got back into C++ and this is just beyond me. This cmd app, when compiled using the debugger in VS2022, looks perfectly as it should. However, when I run the compiled project executable, a seemingly random piece of text often [changes its color to the default white.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtQxu.png)

It's obviously not noticeable when it happens with white text, but I intend to use SetConsoleTextAttribute (or any other way to print colored text) in my program, as well as Unicode support, which _getline does just fine.

It appears to be caused by wcout, as removing _setline and changing them back to the narrow type fixed the issue. However, just removing _setline doesn't do anything.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    fflush(stdout);
    (void)_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 10);
    
    wcout << L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n";
    wcout << L"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n";
    
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 11);

    wcout << L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n";
    wcout << L"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n";

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12);

    wcout << L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n";
    wcout << L"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n";

    cin.get();
}
```

EDIT: Using wmain instead of main and calling fflush wherever it made the tiniest bit of sense didn't fix anything either. Weird.

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce.  Where does `PrintColoredMsg` come from?

Comment: It’s in the lyoUtil.h file (should be visible on the GitHub page). I can upload the solution file too, if that helps.

Comment: You aren't flushing `wcout` before changing the text attributes.

Comment: Also, please copy/paste a minimal reproducible program into the question. Linking to a github repo means that when the repo changes, this question will stop making sense, which will not be helpful to future programmers who are trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen My bad. I'm quite new to this and didn't bother checking what's enough to reproduce this issue.

Comment: About the flushing, is calling wcout << flush; before every SetConsoleTextAttribute call enough? It doesn't seem to have fixed the problem yet.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the tour & HC pages, and sorry for not doing my research beforehand. I'll delete the question and come back later with a suitable one, if that's acceptable.

Comment: @KenWhite I edited the title & post with an MRE. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, feel free to write a formal answer down below rather than including a footnote to the question

Comment: @alterigel Heh, I didn't even bother to check if I could do that! I added one using text from the footnote.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it! Using wmain instead of _setline, setting locale to "" at the beginning and flushing stdout before main returns 0 makes the problem disappear with Unicode still being supported.

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int wmain() {
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 10);
    
    wprintf(L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n");
    wprintf(L"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n");
    
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 11);

    wprintf(L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n");
    wprintf(L"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n");

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12);

    wprintf(L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n");
    wprintf(L"sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n");

    cin.get();
}
```